# How to make Menu Button Selected when Menu is Opened?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there anyway to make unity automatically select the first button in my menu when the menu is first opened so that the player can use their keyboard to navigate through the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

[`button.Select();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.Select.html)

There is difference between *Selecting* and *Highlighting*.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! I tried that before, but I had this problem. Let's say the i was at my main menu and the button was selected using `button.Select()`, when i click on another button in the menu, to open a sub menu, and go back to the main menu, that button is no longer selected @MaifeeUIAsad

Comment: Inside the second `button`'s `onClick()` write `button.Select()` again.